# Neovim stop compiling typescript with Neomake and Typescript-Vim

Tags: javascript, vim, typescript, neovim

I am writing Typescript in Neovim, with plugins `leafgarland/typescript-vim` and `benekastah/neomake`, among others, and whenever I save the file gets compiled.

My understanding (I could be wrong) is that when a file is opened, created or saved `Neomake` is run as indicated by `au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufWritePost * Neomake`. I still want this to happen so that I can get error messages displayed on save, but I don't want it to compile the Typescript file I am working on.

Removing `typescript-vim` stops the compilation but there are no error messages, sytax highlighting or auto-indentation.

Relevant code from `nvim/nvimrc`

```
let g:neomake_typescript_tsc_maker = {
        \ 'args': ['--module', 'system', '--target', 'ES5', '--experimentalDecorators'] }

let g:neomake_warning_sign = { 'text': '!', 'texthl': 'WarnMsg' }
let g:neomake_airline = 1

au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufWritePost * Neomake
```

Here are the rest of my [dotfiles](http://github.com/joshleeb/dotfiles) which contain the rest of the nvimrc.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you think you will get all your error messages if your code is not compiled?

Comment: Perhaps by getting `neomake` to capture the output from `tslint` rather than `tsc`?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `--noEmit` flag to the args of `neomake` when settings the typescript maker, a compiler javascript file no longer appears in the directory upon save.

```
let g:neomake_typescript_tsc_maker = {
    \ 'args': ['--module', 'system', '--target', 'ES5', '--experimentalDecorators', '--noEmit'] }
```